# So, I found this word (한 ) / HAN / HANN. I first encountered it on a KPOP song ((G)-IDLE). Can I use it?

Tags: spoken-korean, korean-culture, history-of-korean

I wanted to use the (한 ) / HAN / HANN word as the title of my story. But, when I searched the meaning of that word I got the results that it is rooted in Korean culture, I wanted to ask if it's okay for a non-Korean to use that word? I want to use it respectfully since it said that (한 ) is part of being Korean and I do not want to water down its meaning.

In my story (The characters are not Korean), I was about to use (한 ) as a feeling of indescribable rage and anger due to a broken heart (Similar to the (G)-IDLE song itself) but I had my doubts upon knowing it is deeper than just that. I appreciate it if someone would answer, Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Koreans generally don't believe in the concept of cultural appropriation: we are happy when we see other people enjoying Korean culture, so you don't have to worry too much about being "respectful."

That said, if you use a distinctly Korean word as your story's title and you don't convincingly pull it off, it may come across as a cheap trick, like you just use some exotic word to make the story sound more "fashionable."  So you may want to learn a bit more about the concept of 한 to make it more naturally integrated to your story.  Just my two cents.

- Also I don't think anyone ever wrote 한 as "hann"...